# Como editar uma mensagem de commit incorreta no Git?

Tags: git

Como editar uma mensagem de commit incorreta no Git? Podem citar exemplos?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Existem 3 situações diferentes, que vão ficando cada vez mais complexas:

1. **Editar o último commit local - *ANTES DO PUSH*:**
   O `git commit --amend` vai abrir seu editor, com o conteúdo da mensagem do último commit e você pode editar tranquilamente.
2. **Editar commits mais antigos - *ANTES DO PUSH*:**
   Você vai precisar fazer um rebase do seu histórico, que é mais complexo que o processo anterior:

   ```
   $ git rebase -i HEAD~3 # Mostra a lista dos 3 últimos commits
   ```

   A lista vai ser mais ou menos assim:

   ```
   pick e499d89 Delete CNAME
   pick 0c39034 Better README
   pick f7fde4a Change the commit message but push the same commit.

   # Rebase 9fdb3bd..f7fde4a onto 9fdb3bd
   #
   # Commands:
   #  p, pick = use commit
   #  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
   #  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
   #  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
   #  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
   #  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
   #
   # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
   #
   # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
   #
   # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
   #
   # Note that empty commits are commented out
   ```

   Altere `pick` para `reword` nos commits que você quer editar a mensagem:

   ```
   pick e499d89 Delete CNAME
   reword 0c39034 Better README
   reword f7fde4a Change the commit message but push the same commit.
   ```

   Salve e feche o arquivo. Depois disso o git vai abrir cada um dos commits marcados com `reword` para edição. Edite as mensagens, salve e feche.
3. **Alterar os commits DEPOIS DO PUSH**
   Antes de mais nada, isso é ***altamente não recomendado***.
   Isso pode quebrar o respositório e dar muito trabalho.
   99.9% das vezes é melhor deixar o commit errado.

   Para alterar o histórico depois do push, basta seguir um dos passos acima e depois executar:

   ```
   git push --force
   ```

Fontes:
1. [Documentação do git](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Reescrevendo-o-Hist%C3%B3rico)
2. [Guia do Github - em Inglês](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/)

Answer (score 12):

```
git commit --amend -m "Nova mensagem"
```

Answer (score 9):

Basta realizar um `--amend`:

```
git commit --amend
```

Ele abrirá o editor de texto com a mensagem do último commit e você pode atualizar a mensagem.